# Show navigation to Controller programatically

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am changing a menu VC over from StoryBoard to programatic operation.

When I want to load another VC I was using the Action Segue "Show".

The temporary code I am using works but pops the VC over the top. Can you action the "Show" equivalent programatically, and if so how?

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SunriseSunsetResultsViewController")
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How about, uh, `show`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621377-show

Comment: Hi - I found that and presumed it might be the answer but found no supporting information on-line, such as SO, on how people use it hence the reason for this post. I have tried various implementations such as func show(_ vc: DistanceFromSunViewController, sender: self ) but can't crack it...

Comment: Well, I don't know what you mean by "crack it". It does work, _if_ you are in a navigation interface. Presumably you were in a navigation interface when you were doing this with the storyboard, so that needs to stay the same.

Comment: By crack it I mean get it to work. I had tried self, UITableViewCell, UINavigationController etc but most of the time the compiler comes back with an "Expected '{' in body of function declaration" style error. I do try and sort my own issues out but this seems to be one of those more obscure commands with very little supporting information of the web. Many thanks for your steers. They are appreciated.

Comment: "Expected '{' in body of function declaration" style error" Ok but that's totally unrelated to the question you asked.

Comment: No but it's an error I'm getting ;-).

Am working along the lines of:  let vc:UIViewController
                let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                vc: UINavigationController = storyBoard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DistanceFromSunViewController") as! UINavigationController
                show(vc, sender:nil )

Comment: Don't try to show code in a comment, that's pointless. If you have a new question, ask it as a separate question. Meanwhile I've given an answer to the question you actually asked.

Comment: Cracked along the lines of:  let vc:UIViewController
                let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DistanceFromSunViewController") as! UIViewController
                show(vc, sender:nil )

Whilst the Show command wasn't well documented the showDetailViewController command was. Many thanks for your prods and will work my way through your advice. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what a Show segue used to do, replace `present` with `show`:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SunriseSunsetResultsViewController")
self.show(newViewController, sender: self)
```

Note, however, that this will do the same thing as `present` unless `self.navigationController` is not `nil`. In other words, you cannot do the sideways navigation you were doing before unless a navigation controller is in charge of the interface.

Instead of `show` you could say `pushViewController` etc., but the same caveat applies. Only a navigation controller can do what you were doing previously.